# Do some authors call a "monoid" a "semigroup"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology, semigroups, monoid, semigroup-of-operators

I'm reading *A Short Course on Operator Semigroups* by Engel and Nagel, and they say on page 2:

> A family $\left(T(t)\right)_{t \geq 0}$ of bounded linear operators on a Banach space is called  a strongly continuous (one parameter) semigroup if it satisfies the functional equation \begin{align} T(t + s) &= T(t)T(s) \text{ for all} t,s \geq 0, \\ T(0) &= I \end{align} and is strongly continuous... [in a way they go on to define].

In other words, this `semigroup' has an identity. But I thought a semigroup with an identity is called a monoid? So I'm wondering if I'm wrong, or if this field is just called *operator semigroup theory* for historical reasons, even though a modern algebraist would call these objects monoids?

Comment: Some people study the case where there isn't an identity, i.e. strictly consider $s, t>0$.

Comment: Every monoid is a semigroup, just like every human is an ape.

Comment: Should it be $T(t)T(s)?$ If not, what is $S?$

Comment: "Semigroup of operators" is well-established terminology at this point; I have no idea why it's not consistent with the terminology in abstract algebra but this sort of thing just happens sometimes and we just have to deal with it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are correct. I've edited it.

Comment: Thanks all. Very helpful. "Every human is an ape," love that.